# ViewController Link to interface builder

Tags: ios

I'm a newbie in ios development... I created a Windows based application. How do I link a view to a controller I created? How do I go to the next view when button is clicked?

Comment: Do you want to push the new view or present it modally?

Comment: Right well you don't link a view to a view controller, its kind of the other way around. If you want to push a viewController you will need to use a navigation controller. I would highly suggest reading through some tutorials or getting a book.....

Comment: Adding a navigation controller: [tutorial](http://dialogtree.com/2011/05/adding-a-uinavigationcontroller-programmatically-within-xcode-4/)

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't link a view to a view controller -- it's the other way around. Add an IBOutlet to your view controller that will point to the view in your .xib or storyboard. Then, in IB, drag a connection from the view to the view controller and choose that outlet. This process is [described in detail in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/03_ConfiguringUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611-CH7-SW6).

To move to the next screen when you click a button, you'll create an IBAction method in your view controller. You can then drag a connection from your button to that view controller and select the action. When the button is tapped, the action method will be sent. The code in the action can then call an appropriate method to transition to the next controller. Alternately, you can use storyboards and segues, and have the button trigger a segue to the next view. You'll find a description of the target/action system in the same document that I linked above.